# How do I map data from a vector of bytes to a structure in Rust?

Tags: arrays, vector, struct, rust

I'm writing a program to manipulate wave audio files. I'd like to have a data structure to represent the file header and I implemented it the following way:

```
struct WaveFile {
    riff:               [u8; 4], //Marks the file as riff file, value should be: "RIFF"
    file_size:          u32,     //Size of the overall file
    wave:               [u8; 4], //File Type Header. Always should equal "WAVE"
    format:             [u8; 4], //Format chunk marker, sample value: "fmt" with null termination character
    format_len:         u32,     //Length of format data (should be 16 bytes as above)
    format_type:        [u8; 2], //1 - PCM, 3 - IEEE float, 6 - 8bit A law, 7 - 8bit mu law
    num_of_channels:    [u8; 2], // Number of Channels
    sample_rate:        [u8; 4], //Sample Rate in Hz
    byte_rate:          [u8; 4], // bytes per second of recording (Sample Rate * BitsPerSample * Channels) / 8
    audio_type:         [u8; 2],  //1 - 8bit mono, 2 - 8bit stereo / 16bit mono, 4 - 16bit stereo
    bits_per_sample:    [u8; 2], //Bits per sample
    data:               [u8; 4], // Sample value: “data” - data chunk header. Marks the beginning of the data section.
    size_of_data:       [u8; 4], //Size of data section
}
```

I've also got a vector with data read from the file. These are snippets of code to show you the data structures I use:

```
struct MyFile {
    content: fs::File,
    metadata: fs::Metadata,
}

let mut audio_file = MyFile {
    content: fs::File::open("gitarka_C3.wav").expect("Couldn't open a file."),
    metadata: fs::metadata("gitarka_C3.wav").expect("Couldn't get file metadata"),
};

let mut file_data = Vec::new();

audio_file
    .content
    .read_to_end(&mut file_data)
    .expect("Couldn't copy file contents to vector");
```

Now that I have my vector of data and a structure describing the wave file header, I'd like to read data from the vector and write it to the structure.

1. Can I copy the first 44 bytes of the vector to the 44 byte chunk of memory allocated for my `WaveFile` structure? I'd like to avoid copying the data from vector to structure field by field.
2. Is there a better way to create a human readable data structure describing the header? I know in C I could create macros defining specific offsets and sizes and use a simple array (which would solve the copying problem).

Comment: If you want to do anything that depends on the memory layout of the struct `WaveFile`, you need to add the `#[repr(C)]` attribute. The Rust default representation does not make any guarantees about memory layout.

Comment: But you are probably better of implementing a parser for the wave file format in `nom`.

Comment: One solution from the duplicates [applied to your specific case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eae7f4efd3d006a9b32799eda49a288e).